# Run interactive process inside already-running console application without opening new window

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, io-redirection, processstartinfo

I realize this looks like a lot of other questions out there, but I looked at all of them for hours and never found the real answer I needed, so hear me out:

This is for a .NET C# console application. Within it, I wanted to call a Windows executable using `Process.Start`, but *without it opening a new console window* when run. I also wanted the executable to be able to output to the console and respond to user input normally.

How do you do this? Set `ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow`, or `ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle`? Try to make input/output redirection work for hours on end?

---

EDIT: *smh*... this is different from the "possible duplicates" out there because:

- This is for a console application that wants to run **a Windows command seamlessly within itself**, as if the command was part of the console application itself. For example: create a new C# console application and make it run the Windows `copy` command.
- Additionally, I needed the user to be able to *interact* with the running command (e.g., if `copy` asks whether to overwrite I wanted the user to answer), so hiding the window as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/836436/63209), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1469790/63209) possible answers is a no-no.
- I wanted to stress how the *single* `UseShellExecute` property solves the problem, without the misleading fluff (e.g., about I/O redirection) in answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14765016/63209), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c), which again, made me waste hours.

Comment: Nice... downvotes w/o comment or consideration for how this could prevent someone from wasting hours away... *smh* :-|

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm a little confused as to how that differs from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden). Are you saying that you're running console application *A* and you want to start executing console application *B* instead "seamlessly" (i.e. make it look like application *B* is just "picking up where *A* left off")?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a C# console application with the console hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden)

Comment: @EJoshuaS: Thanks for caring to comment, and yes, seamlessly, and interactive, are the key words! I edited the question and title to hopefully clarify how this is different.

Comment: That makes sense, then - I retracted my dupe vote and upvoted b/c this seems like a useful thing to be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute=false`. That's it! (I know, I couldn't believe it myself).

After hours of trying all sorts of things, this is what worked for me - without even setting `CreateNoWindow=true`! Also, at the end of it all, I did find [this MSDN post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2006/09/28/how-to-start-a-console-app-in-a-new-window-the-parents-window-or-no-window/) that confirms what I found out. Go figure!